# Uderstanding netstat output

Tags: windows, networking, port, socket, netstat

When I run `netstat -b` on Windows 10
I get lots of results of similar nature

`TCP    127.0.0.1:64248        LocalHostName:64249   ESTABLISHED
 [w3wp.exe]
 TCP    127.0.0.1:64249        LocalHostName:64248   ESTABLISHED
 [w3wp.exe]`

I would like to know what causes connections on ports 64248 and 64249. They both seem to be open and connected on w3wp.exe process. This doesn't seem right and I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

They are app pool connections, you can run "appcmd list wp" to see the PID and app pools running.